# Waiting multiple Tasks on .NET

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

I've a code using multiple functions that returns Task. I am trying to use `Task.WhenAll` to optimize the time and code, but I need to get the return from the tasks. Any tips to deal with it?

This is how my code looks like:

```
var task1 = TaskFcuntionOne();
var task3 = TaskFcuntiontwo();
var task3 = TaskFcuntionThree();

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3);
```

I would like to get a return from the `WhenAll`, is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have successfully awaited `Task.WhenAll`, you know that the tasks are completed, so you can use `task1.Result`, `task2.Result`, etc. to get the individual task results.